# Snap.svg, how do I handle groups of similar objects? (Like classes)

Tags: snap.svg

I just discovered the Snap.svg library for handing svg images in javascript. Is it possible to handle the attributes for objects with classes in some way? I have this code:

```
var s = Snap('#map');

var seat = s.rect(0,0,6,6);

seat.attr({
    fill:'#ccc',
    stroke:'#000',
    strokeWidth:1
});

seat.node.onclick = function(){
    seat.attr("fill","red");
};
```

What I want to do is have the *seat* to be a class, so that I can place new (and remove) seats with the same attributes but just with other coordinates. I would also like the onclick method to work on the entire class, but just affecting the clicked *seat* in that class.

I guess that this is possible but I got stuck thinking about it...

If I could mix the code with jquery to get it to work (if external javascript is required), that would be a preferable soulution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really put a click handler on class, but you can put all the elements in a group (with a handler), and give them all a unique id. You can style the seats via svg or a centralised javascript object with your svg attributes in there. To give a quick example of what I mean, here is a test example...

You don't really need any jquery in this case.

```
// You can use css, or style direct via attributes, or a combination.
.seat {
    fill: blue;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.seathighlight {
    fill: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

s = Snap(400, 620);

var seatGroup = s.g().click( seatClick );
for( a=0; a<10; a++ ) {
    seatGroup.append( s.rect(15*a,10,10,10).attr({ id: 'seat'+a, class: 'seat' }) );
};

function seatClick(e) {
    var el = Snap( e.target );
    el.attr({ class: 'seathighlight' });
    alert( el.attr('id') );
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1uevrjy/2/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall down-voting... and I can't undo it. If you edit the answer, I think I can.